# Как выполнить INSERT данной формы в базу данных Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, insert

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>EMail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>İmya</label>
        <input type="text" name="imya[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Familya</label>
        <input type="text" name="familya[]" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>EMail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>İmya</label>
        <input type="text" name="imya[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Familya</label>
        <input type="text" name="familya[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="#" method="POST">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>EMail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email1" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>İmya</label>
        <input type="text" name="imya1" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Familya</label>
        <input type="text" name="familya1" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>EMail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email2" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>İmya</label>
        <input type="text" name="imya2" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Familya</label>
        <input type="text" name="familya2" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="ok">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST))
 {
      $result1 = "INSERT INTO table_name (email,name,family) 
VALUES ($_POST[email1],$_POST[imya1],$_POST[familya1])";

      $result2 = "INSERT INTO table_name (email,name,family) 
VALUES ($_POST[email2],$_POST[imya2],$_POST[familya2])";

mysql_query($result1);
mysql_query($result2);
 }

?>
```